# Entity Framework Store Object in Column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I currently follow a pattern where I store objects which are serialized and deserialized to a particular column.

This pattern was fine before, however, now due to the frequency of transactions the cost of serializing the object to a JSON string and then later retrieving the string and deserializing back to an object is too expensive.

Is it possible to store an object directly to a column to avoid this cost? I am using Entity Framework and I would like to work the data stored in this column as type Object.

Please advise.

Comment: SQL Server does not have a data type object so what do you want to use for the database type?  Probably a byte[].  So how do you plan to take your objects and convert to byte[]?  Maybe use Marshal methods?  Then what happens if a property is not inline how do you convert to a byte[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON serialization is not fast. It's faster and less verbose than XML, but a lot slower than binary serialization. I would look at third party binary serializers, namely ZeroFormatter, or Wire/Hyperion. For my own stuff I use Wire as a "fast enough" and simple to implement option.

As far as table structure I would recommend storing serialized data in a separate 1..0-1 associated table. So if I had an Order table that I wanted to serialize some extra order-related structure (coming from 3rd party delivery system for example) I'd create another table called OrderDeliveryInfo with a PK of OrderID to join to the Order table to house the Binary[] column for the serialized data. The reason for this is to avoid the cost of retrieving and transmitting the binary blob every time I query Order records unless I explicitly request the delivery info.

Comment: I moved from JSON to MessagePack.